# How to limit frame rate when using getUserMedia with desktopCapturer source?

Tags: electron

Using following to set `getUserMedia` constraints to initiate screen capture.

```js
const sources = await window.api.desktopCapturer.getSources({
  types: ["screen"],
})
constraints = {
  audio: false,
  video: {
    mandatory: {
      chromeMediaSource: "desktop",
      chromeMediaSourceId: sources[0].id,
    },
  },
}
```

For camera source, I set `frameRate: { max: 5 }` to limit frame rate.

When I add `frameRate: { max: 5 }` to above `video` property, following error is thrown.

> Cannot use both optional/mandatory and specific or advanced constraints.

Is it possible to limit frame rate for [desktopCapturer](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/desktop-capturer/) sources?

Answer (score 1):

Solved… `maxFrameRate: 5` is what I was looking for.

Comment: Would be helpful for others if you mention where you've found `maxFrameRate` option