# Electron screen recording stuck at <10fps

Tags: javascript, electron, getusermedia, mediastream, mediadevices

**The goal:**

I want to have an electron app running that records a ~2 min video of a specific window. The window is imagery, not textual, so I'd like HD and >=60 frames per second. I only need it to work on window platforms. Capturing audio would be nice but not my first priority.

**My attempt:**

I've looked at some online examples and figured out how to:

- I use electron's `desktopCapturer.getSources()` to find the specific window source I'm interested in
- I then use `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()` to convert that window source to a [`MediaStream`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream).
- I then use [`MediaRecorder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder) to gather recording chunks from the `MediaStream`
- I aggregate the chunks to a `Blob`, cast to an `ArrayBuffer`, then a `Buffer`.
- Since `MediaRecorder` doesn't support `.mp4`, I use an npm package built on `ffmpeg` to convert the webm buffer to an mp4 buffer.
- I use node's `fs` to write the webm and mp4 buffers to 2 files.

This works ok. The mp4 files have some metadata issue which results in some video players not playing them while other video players can play them; I'm not too concerned about this. The webm videos play fine.

**The issue:**

The recordings have very low frame rates. The file properties don't mention a frames per second or bitrate, the fields are just blank. But it seems like 5 frames per second. I'd like at least 30, or more if possible.

I `console.log` the mediaStream's video track's frame rate, and it says 30. I short circuited the writing to file and just streamed the mediaStream to a `<video>` element, and I still get low frames, so the `MediaRecorder`, and the writing to a file aren't responsible.

**Minimal example:**

```
const {desktopCapturer} = require('electron');

let source, stream, track;

desktopCapturer.getSources({types: ['window']}).then(async sources => {
    // Get the stream
    source = sources.find(source => source.name === 'My Window');
    stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        audio: false,
        video: {
            mandatory: {
                chromeMediaSource: "desktop",
                chromeMediaSourceId: source.id,
            },
        },
    });

    // Print some info about the stream
    track = stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
    let obj = {
        settings: track.getSettings(),
        constraints: track.getConstraints(),
        capabilities: track.getCapabilities(),
    };
    console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2));

    // Project to a <video> element
    let video = document.querySelector('video');
    if (!video) {
        video = document.createElement('video');
        document.body.appendChild(video);
    }
    video.srcObject = stream;
    video.onloadedmetadata = () => video.play();
});
```

**The Track console logs:**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "aspectRatio": 1.7777777777777777,
    "deviceId": "window:4982682:0",
    "frameRate": 30,
    "height": 1440,
    "resizeMode": "crop-and-scale",
    "width": 2560
  },
  "constraints": {
    "deviceId": {
      "exact": "window:4982682:0"
    }
  },
  "capabilities": {
    "aspectRatio": {
      "max": 2560,
      "min": 0.0006944444444444445
    },
    "deviceId": "window:4982682:0",
    "facingMode": [],
    "frameRate": {
      "max": 30,
      "min": 0
    },
    "height": {
      "max": 1440,
      "min": 1
    },
    "resizeMode": [
      "none",
      "crop-and-scale"
    ],
    "width": {
      "max": 2560,
      "min": 1
    }
  }
}
```

**Chrome browser example:**

I tried to do the same thing in a chrome browser and have the same issue. So it doesn't seem electron specific. If I select the same window as I was recording with electron, chrome has the same <10fps video. But if I select the entire screen, then the video gets full 60 or so fps. So somehow, selecting the specific window reproduces the issue. Selecting the entire screen doesn't work for my case though, since there are other windows open that I do not want to record.

```
    // Run this in the dev console

    stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia();
    
    let video = document.querySelector('video');
    if (!video) {
        video = document.createElement('video');
        document.body.appendChild(video);
    }
    video.srcObject = stream;
    video.onloadedmetadata = () => video.play();
```

**[edit] Partial fix:**

After disabling window's "background recording" setting, I see a big improvement in the stream's fps. Though, it's still not nearly as smooth as the built in window's xbox-game-bar recording (which I'm trying to replace).

Comment: How did you resolve the permissions issue? I'm stuck at trying to make my app ask screen recording permission

Answer (score 0):

Your call to .getUserMedia() mentions some video contraints about the source device. To control frame rate, to the constraints object add

```
frameRate: {min: 10, ideal: 60, max: 60 }
```

Other constraints, like for size, are available too. [See this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia#parameters).

It's better to use min / ideal / max rather than just saying

```
 frameRate: 60
```

If you give a min / ideal / max range you'll get *something* even if the capture can't keep up at a higher frame rate.

You set the bandwidth for the compressed video data stream in the MediaRecorder constructor. You didn't ask about that.

Comment: Maybe I've misunderstood the docs/explanations online, but my understanding is the `frameRate` constraint is valid for webcams but not screen captures. When I try using it, I get `"Unknown name of constraint detected" / "frameRate"` error

Comment: You're right. Here's a related question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70142727/how-to-limit-frame-rate-when-using-getusermedia-with-desktopcapturer-source

Comment: `maxFrameRate`, like in the question you linked, does effect the stream fps. But when I set `minFrameRate` to 60, or 120, it doesn't make a difference. And it's noticeably choppier than widow's xbox-game-bar recordings.